# Error when i try to create a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Error message:

*SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 15*

```html
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER fill_address AFTER UPDATE ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  UPDATE orders
  SET address = CONCAT_WS(
   ' ',
   payment_method,
   payment_address_1,
   payment_address_2,
   payment_city,
   payment_postcode,
   payment_country,
   payment_zone)
  WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM INSERTED)
 END //
DELIMITER
```

Comment: You are missing all delimiters.

Comment: anyway the same error

Comment: You don't have any delimiter, you attempt to run all your code as a giant single statement, which it isn't. You've edited the code to add "Hey, MySQL, I'll be using | as delimiter" but you don't actually do that.

Comment: I added a delimiter but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

When you only run a single statement you don't need to do anything special. You send the code to the server and you're done:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer_count FROM customer
```

However, if you want to send more than one query at a time you need to tell MySQL where each statement ends. Otherwise, the SQL parser will treat everything as one query and will abort parsing wherever the query stops making sense:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer_count FROM customer
SELECT COUNT(*) AS order_count FROM order
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS order_count FROM order' at line 2

In almost all MySQL clients out there, default delimiter is semicolon:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer_count FROM customer;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS order_count FROM order;
```

Triggers and other pieces of user defined routines are a special case because you need to distinguish between two situations:

1. Element creation
2. Element execution

When you create the trigger, everything you send is a single statement: all the CREATE TRIGGER code. When the trigger executes, each statement inside the trigger body is an independent query. How can we distinguish both situations with the *same code*? The trick is to use the standard `;`  separator in the trigger body (where we don't have control about it) but temporarily change the delimiter when executing the CREATE TRIGGER code (where we can use the DELIMITER command offered by most clients).

The first version of your code was missing all separators. Current version is missing trigger body separators.